# List all Linux users without systen users

Tags: linux, debian, system, administrator

I would like to list all users in Linux without showing systen-user.
How can I make this only the username .

For example `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`, I can see all users + system users.

Comment: Is `ls /home` good enough?

Comment: @kaylum No please with /etc/passwd and filter it

Comment: I was just trying to get you to think. A non-system user will have both a home directory and a shell. Just parse those fields in the passwd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows all users with uid less than 999:

```
awk  -F':' '$3>999 {print $1 " uid: " $3}' /etc/passwd | column -t | grep -v nobody
```

EDIT:

With `cut` showing only human users:

```
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | egrep ':[0-9]{4}$' | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Thank you that is good   awk -F ':' '$3>999{print $1}' /etc/group | grep -v nobody

Comment: If it helped you,  remember to mark as answered...  and no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : `awk -F: '$6 ~ /\/home/ {print}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: Thx can we make this with cut ? When Yes how

Comment: Maybe you can, but not only with the cut (using multiple pipe with multiple commands).