# List all users names of the Linux system by calling c++ function

Tags: c++, linux

I would like to get all users names of the Posix system by calling c++ function from some library. Found only option to use call bash commands like this  [List all Linux users without systen users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482163/list-all-linux-users-without-systen-users) from c++ programm

Comment: C++ doesn't know about linux, it is OS independent.  You'll need to use system calls or get a library.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`getpwent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html)?

Comment: @NathanOliver agree with I edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX provides this functionality via the [`getpwent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main() {
    while (true) {
        errno = 0; // so we can distinguish errors from no more entries
        passwd* entry = getpwent();
        if (!entry) {
            if (errno) {
                std::cerr << "Error reading password database\n";
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            break;
        }
        std::cout << entry->pw_name << '\n';
    }
    endpwent();
}
```

Comment: it is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!